# Transaction sharing in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Is it possible to reuse the same transaction between multiple processes with Postgres? Or any other RDBMS? Is there name for such concept and does it make any sense?

One possible use case would be two service instances (different processes) modifying related set of entities within one distributed transaction.

For example, imagine a website that displays music playlists. Plain users can see playlists, but editors can collaborate on playlist editing. Editors would modify lists, but viewers wouldn't see latest changes until one of editors saves (commits) changes.

This is just illustrative example, and would take a different approach to the design, without relying on distributed transactions. I'm just interested in the concept of distributed transactions and it's plausability, since I'm not expert in the field.

Comment: Also take a look at this to notify user about a data change http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-notify.html.

Comment: Thnx, didn't know postgres can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to have a process, method or service that interrogates the two backend services for the necessary information and then executes the operation in a transaction itself.

That said, you're probably looking for a [Two-Phase Commit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html).  Note the warning on that page about leaving commits open for too long.

Comment: I agree, but I'm curious about possibility of transaction sharing. I'm just considering different options in the design, so knowing that such thing is possible would make some of the elements easier to understand and work with.

Comment: Actually, if you can provide a functional scenario for this, I could probably formulate a better answer.

Comment: I added an example, but the question is more of theoretical kind, so please, don't take it for granted.

Comment: That's not a transaction, in the database sense.  It's more like a "gate."  You would have a Moderator Approvals table to release the changes to the wild, and/or a Moderator ID on the playlist table that you can set to the ID of the moderator who approved it.  You would then have a WHERE clause in your query that only captured records that were moderator-approved.

Comment: I should've find a better example, but it just illustrates the idea, not actual design problem. I understand and appreciate the design your proposing, it's just not quite what I'm aiming at with my question.

Comment: Related: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/OFF769BEAA.1A208A25-ON6525776F.00322EB1-6525776F.00325EC9@ibsplc.com

Comment: Can you please just add the link to your answer? That was great, many thanks.

Comment: I would never assume that RDBMS would make possible explicit management of two-phase commits. Well... I guess a good book on postgres is in order...